# Procurar sequencia de palavras desordenadas de uma lista em um texto

Tags: python, python-3.x

Existe alguma maneira de ter uma lista de palavras não ordenada e procurar se existe uma sequência delas em um texto?

Exemplo:

```
lista = ["dia", "noite", "tarde", "é", "está", "bonito", "o", "a", "muito", "feio"]

texto = "Hoje é sábado, vamos sair pois o dia está bonito. Até mais tarde."
```

Match -> "o dia está bonito"

Eu consigo encontrar todas as palavras da lista, mas não estão ordenadas

```
lista = ["dia", "noite", "tarde", "é", "está", "bonito", "o", "a", "muito", "feio"]
texto = "Hoje é sábado, vamos sair pois o dia está bonito. Até mais tarde."

frase = []
for palavras in lista:
    if palavras in texto:
        frase.append(palavras)

print (' '.join(frase))
```

Output:

> dia tarde é está bonito o a

Inclusive o "a" está aparecendo não sei porque!

Comment: É necessário retirar a pontuação do teu input, neste caso "bonito", não estará incluído: https://repl.it/Mp7s . Certo? É isso que queres?

Comment: @Miguel Obrigada, pensei que haveria um jeito de extrair "o dia está bonito" que é uma sequência com palavras da lista.

Comment: Pitanga... Bom exercício (; : https://repl.it/Mp7s/4 . Assim encontramos todas as sequências (mais do que uma palavra) num texto

Comment: Uau!!! Estou sem palavras @Miguel
Vou comentar todo este código que você fez. E depois vou tentar refazer sozinha. Que maravilha, obrigada!

Comment: De nada ... Boa sorte

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Inclusive o "a" está aparecendo não sei porque!

O código como está passa em cada palavra da `lista` e vê se ela existe no texto. E não tem que existir como palavra solta, basta existir no meio e isso é o motivo pelo qual o `a` aparece:

```
texto = "Hoje é sábado, vamos sair pois o dia está bonito. Até mais tarde."
#o 'a' está aqui---^---
```

O operador `in` do Python neste caso verifica se o texto contem em questão.

Para o seu objetivo basta inverter a logica do `for` percorrendo o texto palavra a palavra e verificando se ela existe na lista. Isto não só resolve o problema do `a` assim como lhe garante a ordem:

```
lista = ["dia", "noite", "tarde", "é", "está", "bonito", "o", "a", "muito", "feio"]
texto = "Hoje é sábado, vamos sair pois o dia está bonito. Até mais tarde."

frase = []
for palavras in texto.split(' '): #agora texto e com split(' ') para ser palavras
    if palavras in lista: #para cada palavra agora verifica se existe na lista
        frase.append(palavras)

print (' '.join(frase))
```

[Veja o exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/Xb9Fzp)

Note que a divisão das palavras com espaços irá apanhar as palavras com os carateres como `.` e `,`, obtendo palavras como `bonito.` ou `tarde.`, fazendo com que o código não as encontre

Pode contornar este problema de muitas formas. Uma das mais simples passa por retirar estes careteres antes de analisar:

```
texto2 = texto.replace('.','').replace(',','');
```

[Veja no Ideone como fica com está pre analise](https://ideone.com/PGDug7)

Pode até fazer algo mais genérico e criar uma lista de careteres de pontuação a remover e fazer a remoção através de uma função personalizada:

```
def retirar(texto, careteres):
    for c in careteres:
        texto = texto.replace(c, '')

    return texto
```

E agora utilizar essa função sobre o texto original:

```
texto2 = retirar(texto, ".,");
```

[Veja também este exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/nW9HsY)

Comment: Entendi a explicaçao sobre o "a"! Obrigada! Mas no caso a saída do programa é: "é o dia está" e o "é" nao está seguido de nenhuma palavra da lista e além disso o "bonito" nao foi reconhecido. Pensei que haveria um jeito de extrair "o dia está bonito" que é uma sequência com palavras da lista. Obrigada!

Comment: @pitanga O problema tem a ver com o `,` e o `.` que ficam nas palavras quando o texto é partido em palavras. Pode resolver este problema de inúmeras maneiras, em que o mais simples seria retirar estes separadores antes de interpretar as palavras.